# insert song to playlist returns null

Tags: java, android, playlist, mediastore

I was trying to build a music player application , and I wanted to add a feature in order to add a song to a playlist.Here is the code:

```
public static void addToPlaylist(ContentResolver resolver,SongDetails songDetails,int  playlistId) {
    String[] cols = new String[] {
            "count(*)"
    };
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistId);
    Cursor cur = resolver.query(uri, cols, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    final int base = cur.getInt(0);
    cur.close();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, Integer.valueOf(base +   songDetails.getId()));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, songDetails.getId());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DISPLAY_NAME, songDetails.getSongTitle());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST, songDetails.getArtistName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATA, songDetails.getSongData());

    Log.i("URI:",resolver.insert(uri, values)+"");
}
```

and in the logs I always get:

```
URI: null
```

which means that the song is not added to the playlist.Does anybody have any idea why the song is not added?

Comment: Don't you want `base + 1` in `PLAY_ORDER`?

Comment: It returned null as well

Comment: And where do you set the songDetails `id`?

Comment: I set it in the activity which calls this code, right before using this code.

Comment: so , you are indicating that there are mandatory fields , which are?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using this method and it worked for me.

```
 public static String addTracksToPlaylist(final long id, List<MediaData> tracks, final Context context) {
    int count = getPlaylistSize(id, context);
    ContentValues[] values = new ContentValues[tracks.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++) {
        values[i] = new ContentValues();
        values[i].put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, i + count + 1);
        values[i].put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, tracks.get(i).getId());
    }
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", id);
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    int num = resolver.bulkInsert(uri, values);
    resolver.notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://media"), null);
    return String.format(context.getString(R.string.ADDED_TO_PLAYLIST), num, context.getString(R.string.CURRENT));
 }
```

Retrieving tracks from playlist:

```
public static Cursor getTrackListFromPlaylist(Context context, long plid) {
        String[] MEDIA_COLUMNS = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MINUTES + "||':'||" + SECONDS + " as " + FORMATTED_DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID
        };
        return query(context, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", plid),
                MEDIA_COLUMNS, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    }
```

Comment: If we say that we are going to use this code , how are we gonna retrieve the name of the song given the current playlist , if we didn't insert the name of the track besides the its id?

Comment: well , in the code you inserted the id of the audio , so far so good , but how can you get the data , title , and the other stuff without inserting them in the first place?

Comment: Afaik they are bounding automatically when you insert id for the track into playlist members. There is no need to keep same data twice.

Comment: Well , when I try to insert a song by the way above , and when I log the resulting URI , I get content://media/external/audio/playlists/3/members/70
but , when I query the second method to get the number of tracks I get the previous number , which indicates nothing has changed.Do you know why?

Comment: I'm trying to add a track in a playlist which contains just one track , and every time I get size of 1 , which should be 2 if it's really working.

Comment: That's strange, cause i've tested this code on many devices, including devices with custom ROMS, also on emul, and everywhere worked fine.

Comment: My bad , I was giving the content resolver the id of the selected item from the list adapter , not the id the playlist, thank you so much for your help.